# Tratando de almacenar datos con Ajax obtengo el siguiente error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, ajax

Estoy realizando un código para un examen diagnostico y guardar las respuestas sin actualizar el Blade, por lo que estoy tratando de usar Ajax pero me da el error de "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Ya verifique y mi ruta si es Post:

Leí algo sobre usar URL solicita https y por eso aparece el error del GET pero no se como evitar ese detalle.

Coloco el código que interviene

Ruta:

```
`Route::post('/respuestas/store',[App\Http\Controllers\PreguntaController::class, 'saveRes'])->name('saveRes');`
```

Blade:

```
`@extends('layouts.app')


@section('titulo','Examen')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            
            <h1>INICIA TU PRUEBA</h1>
            <!--Regresa el nombre de la materia accediendo mediante la relacion-->
            @foreach($esp as $key => $ma1)
            @endforeach

            <h2>Materia {{$ma1->materia->nombre}}</h2>
            @foreach($esp as $key => $ma1)
            <!--Devuelve la pregunta-->
            <label>{{$key+1}}.- {{$ma1->pregunta}}</label>
            <br>
            <!--Devuelve las respuestas-->
            @foreach($ma1->respuesta as $key=>$resp)
                <form id="regResultado" method="post">
                 @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="p1">{{$resp->respuesta}}</label>
                        <input  type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="p" id="p" value="{{$resp->id}}">
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="sa" name="suma" value="{{$resp->suma}}" hidden="" id="suma">
                        <input type="sa" name="pr" value="{{$ma1->id}}" hidden="" id="pr">
                        <input type="sa" name="user" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}" hidden="" id="user">
                        
                    </div>
            
                @endforeach
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                </form>
            <br>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >

    $('#regResultado').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var suma = $('#suma').val();
        var id_respuesta = $('#p').val();
        var id_pregunta = $('#pr').val();
        var id_user = $('#user').val();
        var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('saveRes') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data:{
                suma: suma,
                id_usuario: id_user,
                id_pregunta: id_pregunta,
                id_respuesta: id_respuesta,
                _token:_token
            },

            success:function(response){
                if(response){
                    toatr.success('El registro fue exitoso', 'Nuevo registro',{timeOut:3000});
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>

@endsection`
```

Controlador:

```
`public function saveRes(Request $request){

        $resultado = new Resultado();

        $resultado->suma =$request->suma;
        $resultado->id_respuesta=$request->id_respuesta;
        $resultado->id_pregunta=$request->id_pregunta;
        $resultado->id_usuario=$request->id_usuario;

        $resultado->save();

        return back();

    }`
```

Les agradecería el apoyo, es la primera vez que intento implementar el post mediante Ajax y no estoy muy familiarizado con sintaxis o errores como este.

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Desde Network me muestra que es POST, adjunto imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente esta situación se da bajo dos escenarios.

1. Que el request se esté dando realmente por medio de GET, aunque viendo su código parece correcto el envío de un POST. Sin embargo, esto lo confirmaría por medio del los datos de "Network" usando "developer tools" del navegador <kbd>F12</kbd>:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Lo otro es que estés sobreescribiendo el mismo route posteriormente, por ejemplo:

```php
Route::post('/respuestas/store', [
    App\Http\Controllers\PreguntaController::class, 'saveRes'
])->name('saveRes');

Route::get('/respuestas/get', [
    App\Http\Controllers\PreguntaController::class, 'saveRes'
])->name('saveRes');
```

*Nótese que tienen el mismo route name*

Para confirmar este último punto, se puede ejecutar el comando `php artisan route:list > rutas.txt`. Esto creará un archivo de texto donde se pueden ver todas las URLS registras en los routes, así puede determinar si existen duplicados.

Comment: Gracias por responder, intente lo mencionado pero aun así no funciona, desde Network, me muestra que es POST. actualice la pregunta con la imagen del Network.